# logstash plugin for jenkins

Tags: logstash, logstash-forwarder, logstash-configuration

I am attempting to use logstash pluin for jenkins https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logstash+Plugin and have it configured to work with elasticsearch. Seems I do not know why my logs from jenkins are not being forwarded I have logstash runnning on port 6379 and looking for fetch and sort a trace.log

Answer (score 0):

In which port is your elastic search running? You need to configure the host and port of the elastic search in your Jenkins instance. For example http::9200. in general you could access the logs of the Jenkins in Elastic search under port 9200.

Answer (score -1):

What do your logstash config files look like; in particular your input block? Is 6379 the port you have logstash running on? I think you may want to try specifying elasticsearch host & port info here. Even though it's a logstash plugin, it seems to be skipping logstash all together and sends it straight to the indexer (in your case elasticsearch).